# Cannot draw an image.

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, cgcontextdrawimage

I have a `UIImageView` within an `UIViewController` and want to add a simple image on the existing imageView.

The viewDidLoad-method looks like this:

```
    UIImage *test;
    test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"position-dot.png"];

    [test drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100,100) ];
```

A part of the error-message I receive look like this:

```
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

`CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error`.

I tested to reset my iOS Simulator (solution in other threads about this), but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You want to display the `UIImage` on a `UIImageView` or render it on top of what is currently displayed by it?

Comment: You should be able to resolve this by wrapping your code in calls to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() and UIGraphicsEndImageContext().

Comment: @Alladinian: The second alternative. On top of what is currently displayed by it.

Comment: geraldWilliam, do you have an example?

Comment: Is using a second UIImageView an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the approach in my above comment does silence the warning, I was finding that the image was not displaying as I expected. I found that the easiest way to make drawAtPoint work was to subclass UIView and put the exact code that you have into the implementation of drawRect: like so.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    UIImage *test;
    test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"position-dot"];
    [test drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
}
```

Then, in your controller:

```
MyViewSubclass *view = [[MyViewSubclass alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: Thanks, that did show the image. But the image that it is supposed to be on top is now black. It is black even if I add it as a sub view to the ImageView (the imageview that now is black). Why is that?

Comment: Oh right. Essentially, both images need to be drawn into the same view. See this forum answer [http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/113055-saving-overlay-and-ui-captured-image-to-single-photo.html] from @DuncanC for an example of how to implement a "watermarked" image.